# Program is prompting input multiple times from methods

Tags: java, methods, return, return-value

My program is designed to figure out the area of a rectangle through the user's inputs. My code is prompting the user's input twice for both length and width with the second time being the value that the program will use for the calculation. The math is all correct, the only problem that (I know) is happening is the repetition of the prompting of the inputs.

---

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AreaRectangle
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  double length=0;    
  double width=0;     
  double area;      


  getLength(length);
  length= getLength(length);

  getWidth(width);
  width= getWidth(width);

  getArea(length,width); 
  area= getArea(length, width);

  displayData(length, width, area);
 } 

  public static double getLength(double length)
  {
  Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in); 
     double result;

     System.out.println("Enter the Rectangle's Length");

     result= keyboard.nextDouble();

     return result;
  }   

  public static double getWidth(double width)
  {
  Scanner keyboard= new Scanner(System.in); 
     double result;

     System.out.println("Enter the Rectangle's Width");

     result=keyboard.nextDouble();

     return result;
  }


  public static double getArea(double length, double width)
  {
     double result;

     result= (length*width);

     return result;
  }


  public static void displayData(double length, double width, double area)
  {
     System.out.println("The length is "+length+". The width is "+width);
     System.out.println("The area is "+area); 


  }

}
```

Comment: You're calling `getLength` and `getWidth` twice ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

//you have called each method twice

```
  //  getLength(length);
    length = getLength(length);

   // getWidth(width);
    width = getWidth(width);

   // getArea(length, width);
    area = getArea(length, width);

    displayData(length, width, area);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are invoking `getLength()` and `getWidth()` method twice. Fix is very simple, just remove one invocation of each.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  double length=0;    
  double width=0;     
  double area;      


 // getLength(length); not required
  length= getLength(length);

 // getWidth(width); not required
  width= getWidth(width);
```